# How to view the content of my embedded HSQLDB in Eclipse?

Tags: database, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, hsqldb, embedded-database

This is my Spring dataSource:

```
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL);
        dataSource = builder.build();
```

I would like to view the content of my database in Eclipse while developing, for example while debugging. I open the Database Development Perspective in Eclipse, add a new Connection Profile, i choose HSQLDB from the Profile options, i choose the hsqldb.jar from my mvn repo (which i also use in my application), and comes this window:

[image]

When i fill the configuration based on the default configuration data of spring (below), a new profile is added but i don't see the contents of database?

EDIT: 
Spring default configuration from the spring code:

```
driver: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
url: jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb
username: sa
password:
```